# C# & ASP.NET Core 5 Web API :- How To Send List Of string & IFormFile Data Type In Single Post Request Using Multipart/form-data...?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, form-data

I'm trying to add company with multiple employees with their picture.
But I'm facing an issue while posting request, not worrying about internal logic.

There are 2 tables `Company` & `Employee` and I want to add company with multiple employees and their picture in a single post request, but I'm getting like this in Swagger:

[image]

Instead I want array of this... want this block multiple times:

[image]

Please, tell me how can I implement it to get the result I want?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> CreateCompany([FromForm] CreateCompanyRequestViewModel Company)
{
        // 
}
```

EmployeeRequestViewModel

```
public class EmployeeRequestViewModel
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; };
    public IFormFile ProfileImage { get; set; };
}
```

CompanyViewModel

```
public class CreateCompanyRequestViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; };
    public IFormFile CompanyLogo { get; set; };
    public List<EmployeeRequestViewModel> Employees { get; set; };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with postman as below:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Want list of Employees [ having EmployeeName & ProfileImage ] dynamically...

Comment: What does your dynamically mean?

Comment: You could check this document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#collections-1

Comment: Array Of Employees Will Come From Front-End.... don't want To Use hard coded implementation like employee[0], employee [1]... Coz we don't know how many employees user will add...

Comment: unfortunatly,there seems no other default solutions ,may be you could try custom-model-bindinghttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Sorry For Late Reply... It Worked For Above Question... And Handled My Actual Issue With Some Modification...